# Array Formula with Multiple Results and Partial Match

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I need help making it so that "Engine Starting" does not have be an exact match when searching.

[image]

I also would like to add two rows to the top to add a header, but when I do that this happens.

[image]

The Matches will not show the first two results. There is supposed to be a match for Engine starting in Lesson 3 and Lesson 4.

Comment: Can you upload the excel file? It is hard to tell what you are asking for from just the images.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/esbsxzm90eehi75/LineItem.Data---2015-09-24.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: You should revise your question. I am basing this comment from the excel file I just downloaded. What you did by adding two rows on the top is exactly what the excel text box is asking you to do. [From the excel sheet] "1. Add two lines at the top and put a title and the revision number of the TCO"

Comment: Another comment based on the downloaded excel. It looks like you have several sheets of what appears to be lesson plans and titles for the lessons. Your task was to search for the words "Engine Starting" and create a list of the lessons that had the words. Is this correct?

Comment: If my previous comment is correct just use "Crtl+F" to search for "Engine Starting:" Here is an imgur example. <http://i.imgur.com/NCCTQTy.png>. There are different options, the current search was only within this sheet. But you can include other sheets as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inserted two rows, a couple of things happened that caused the shift.

`ROW($B$1:$B$1000)` became `ROW($B$3:$B$1002)`. This is not intended to return the actual row on the worksheet. It is intended to return the *position within* the range referenced by the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a). In your first formula, these were the same because you used `INDEX($A$1:$A$1000, ...` but after inserting two rows it became `INDEX($A$3:$A$1002, ...`. The minimum that `ROW($B$3:$B$1002)` would return would be **3**, not **1** so there was no way you were ever going to get the first row in `$A$3:$A$1002`.

The *k* parameter of the [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) was also intended to return a series of sequential numbers (e.g. *1, 2, 3, ...*). It was originally `ROW(C1)` which would return *1* and then *2, 3, ...* as the formula was filled down. This returned the smallest then the second smallest then the third smallest, etc. After inserting two rows, this became `ROW(C3)` which is going to return the third smallest and go on from there.

Your array¹ formula fixed to reflect the two inserted rows,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$1002, SMALL(IF($E$3=$B$3:$B$1002, ROW($1:$1000)), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Note that `ROW($1:$1000)` and `INDEX($A$3:$A$1002, ...` do not even reflect the same rows **but they are the same number of rows**. `ROW(1:1)` will return *1, 2, 3...* as it is filled down thereby returning the smallest, second smallest, third smallest, etc.

As to your non-exact match, you could apply a wildcard search in a couple of ways. I usually use a [SEARCH² function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) for the wildcard search paired with the [ISNUMBER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25) to deal with non-match `$N/A` returns.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$1002, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$E$3&"*", $B$3:$B$1002)), ROW($1:$1000)), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Using the newer [AGGREGATE³ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can dispense of having to *array*¹ *enter* your formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$1002, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$1000)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$3, $B$3:$B$1002)), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image: Wildcard non-exact search]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula.</sub>

² <sub>The [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) is not case-sensitive. If a case sensitive locating function is required use the [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) instead.</sub>

³ The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you so much, answered my questions perfectly. Only thing is the partial search works but only displays the first result. Is there a way to use the aggregate function but still display multiple results?

Comment: I'm unclear on what the problem is. Please see [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/LineItem.Data---2015-09-24%20%28Jeeped%29.xlsx).